# How to update $scope using Sinon test with $interval.flush and clock.tick

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, sinon, chai

So, I have a plunker setup with the sample code in question:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KcpzxTnwFNnvhYXyPq6B?p=preview

My problem, is that I have a function in home.controller.js

```
PopularMovies.query(function(data) {
  results = data;
  findMovie(results[0]);
  console.log("$interval Start", Date.now());
  $interval(function() {
    ++idx;
    console.log("$interval idx[" + idx + "]", Date.now());
    console.log("results[idx % results.length]", results[idx % results.length]);
    findMovie(results[idx % results.length]);
  }, 5000);
});
```

When triggered, expect it to call `findMovie()` every 5000ms.

To test this, I have a test written in the home.controller.spec.js file:

```
it('should rotate movies every 5 seconds', function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    var myStub = sinon.stub(PopularMovies, 'query').callsFake(function(cb) {
        cb(['tt0076759', 'tt0080684', 'tt0086190']);
    });
    $controller('HomeController', { 
        $scope: $scope,
        $interval: $interval,
        omdbApi: omdbApi,
        PopularMovies: PopularMovies
    });
    $rootScope.$apply();
    // should have a default movie
    console.log("$scope", $scope);
    console.log("$scope.result", $scope.result);
    console.log("results[0].Title", results[0].Title);
    expect($scope.result.Title).to.equal(results[0].Title);
    // should update after 5 seconds
    console.log(Date.now(), this.clock);
    this.clock.tick(5000);
    $interval.flush(5000);    
    console.log(Date.now(), this.clock);
    console.log("$scope", $scope);
    console.log("$scope.result", $scope.result);
    console.log("results[1].Title", results[1].Title);
    expect($scope.result.Title).to.equal(results[1].Title);
// should update after 5 seconds
    this.clock.tick(5000);
    $interval.flush(5000);
    console.log("$scope", $scope);
    console.log("$scope.result", $scope.result);
    console.log("results[2].Title", results[2].Title);
      expect($scope.result.Title).to.equal(results[2].Title);
    // should return to default
    this.clock.tick(5000);
    $interval.flush(5000);
    expect($scope.result.Title).to.equal(results[0].Title);
    this.clock.restore();
});
```

Where my expectation is that `this.clock.tick(5000);` and/or `$interval.flush(5000);` will increment the timer and angular will update the $scope.result.

On the first call, $scope is updated. However, any subsequent timers fails to update the $scope from the spec file.

I've written these tests once before using Jasmine, where I had no problem with the $scope updating. However, I'm trying to transition to Sinon, so please help me get this working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue I had was in the stubbing of the omdb.find service and converting from Jasmine's `Object.fn.calls.mostRecent()` to Sinon's `Object.fn.args`, which doesn't have mostRecent() function. I changed the code to look at the last arg in the args array.

In home.controller.spec.js, I changed

```
var args = _omdbApi_.find.args[0][0];
```

to

```
var args = _omdbApi_.find.args;
args = args[args.length - 1][0];
```

Working code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xroiqBdGOv4phxtnSWbU?p=preview